# Convert Console App to WebJob/Add to MVC6 Website as Dependent Project

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I've written an MVC6 site and a console app that handles Azure messages and blob storage on behalf of the website. Everything works fine on my development machine, and I can successfully deploy and run the site on Azure.

What I'm stumbling over is how to "link" the console app and the mvc6 site so that when I publish the site the console app/webjob automatically gets published.

The console app was built on the default console app template. It's project.json file is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "ConnellData": "1.0.0-*",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish": "1.0.12",
    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "3.2.1",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8",
    "Serilog": "2.2.1",
    "Serilog.Sinks.TextWriter": "2.0.0",
    "UploadFramework": "1.0.0-*",
    "ConnellDBF": "1.0.0-*",
    "PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI": "1.50.4000-beta3b",
    "Zen.Barcode.Rendering.Framework": "3.1.10729.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Configuration": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.IO.Compression": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's built on top of Net46, as is the mvc6 website project.

When I right click on the console app project, there is no option to publish it as an Azure webjob. Similarly, when I right click on the website project, there is no option under Add to add a "dependent" webjob.

I've added a dummy WebJob project, built off the default WebJob template, to the solution, and it has the expected "Publish as Azure WebJob" option. So clearly I have the right stuff installed on my development machine. It's just that I'm missing something in the configuration/setup of the console app (and maybe the website, too).

Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: when you said mvc6 you means asp.net core ?

Comment: yes, it's an mvc6 website built on asp.net core

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed webjobs SDK? I have and I see the "Publish as Azure Webjob" option when I right click on the project in Visual Studio

[Visual Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y01V6.png)

More information here

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/

Comment: Yes, I have. That's why I was able to see that option on the app I added to the solution using the "default" VS WebJob template. The problem is that the option doesn't appear on the net46 console app I wrote, and want to use as a WebJob.

Comment: Did you check the link? There is a section called "Enable WebJobs deployment for an existing Console Application project" which provides you two options to enable deployment of existing console app as webjob.

Comment: Yes, Nasir, I did. In fact, that was one of the links I had found before I posted anything on stackoverflow. The instructions and alternatives were no help, although I ultimately did get a manual upload approach to work...after I stumbled across the UTF-8 BOM issue and resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out why the context menu options involving publishing a console app as a WebJob wouldn't appear. It's probably something to do with the VS2015 tooling not having caught up with ASPNET Core.

In any event, I was able to work around the problem by manually uploading the console app to wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/. I did this via FTP.

However, getting the console app to >>run<< under Azure was another problem. WebJob apps are, generally, launched by the site calling a run.cmd batch file in the . That run.cmd file, in my case, contained a single line calling for the execution of the console app (UploadProcessor.exe, in my case).

Unfortunately, unbeknownst to me, VS2015 by default saves a "UTF-8 Byte Order Marker' in every text file it creates. The Azure processor, for some bizarre reason, doesn't know how to recognize this set of marker characters, and blows up.

The solution is to do a Save As within VS2015 for the run.cmd file, and walk through the options to save the file as UTF-8 >>without<< a BOM. You only have to do that once when you create run.cmd; thereafter, VS2015 will remember your "no BOM" setting.

I wrote about this some more over at http://imperfect.olbert.com/2016/09/23/azure-webjobs-hidden-utf-8-parameters-and-azure/

Hopefully the Azure team will fix this simple but annoying problem.